# Removing constants in mathematical induction?

Tags: induction

For which positive integer n is $21n +127 \leq  3^n$?

Base case: 
\begin{gather}
n=5\\
21(5) + 127 \leq 3^5 = 243\\
232 \leq 243
\end{gather}
Inductive steps:
\begin{gather}
P(n+1) = 21(n+1) + 127 \leq 3^{n+1}\\\\
\text{Using the original base case:}\\
21n+127 \leq 3^n\\
3(21n+127) \leq 3^n\cdot3\\
63n+381\leq3^{n+1}\\\\
\text{Since:}\\
21(n+1) + 127 = 21n+ 148
\leq 63n+381\\
\therefore21(n+1)+127 \leq 3^{n+1}
\end{gather}

Is this an acceptable way to proof the induction for this question? I am using the following logic in my argument wherby i split a constant into two and remove a part of it to fulfill the argument:
\begin{gather}
3\leq5\\
4\leq5\\
(3+1)\leq5\\
\therefore 3\leq5\\
\end{gather}

Comment: This proof is basically correct, though I'd recommend throwing some words in there and make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Your inductive proof is fine for showing the inequality is true for $n \ge 5$.  To complete the question you need to show that the inequality fails for $1,2,3,4$.  You can do this with a bit of computation.  The fact that the inequality is so close at $n=5$ makes it seem likely, but you need to at least state it.